# Proper way to mock HttpClient and send/get cookies

Tags: c#, unit-testing, cookies, moq, dotnet-httpclient

I am using [moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to mock a wrapper I created for `HttpClient` class:

```
public interface IHttpClientWrapper
{
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(Uri uri,
                                        HttpContent content,
                                        CookieContainer cookies = null);
}
```

and in my "normal" implementation of `PostAsync`, I just delegate the call to `HttpClient`

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(Uri uri, HttpContent content, CookieContainer cookies = null)
{
    var client = cookies == null ? new HttpClient()
        : new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookies });

    return client.PostAsync(uri, content);
}
```

So, in my application, everything works fine and I get the cookies set by the server (`cookies.Count` is not `0`)

For my test, I have a `Mock<IHttpClientWrapper>`, and I have set up its `PostAsync` method to return a `new HttpResponseMessage`. I also call `HttpResponseMessage.Headers.AddCookies` method to add 2 cookies to this response.

But when I call my mocked object in a way like this:

```
/* I setup url and content */
var mock = new Mock<IHttpClientHelper>();
mock.Setup(/* setup PostAsync to return the response I create */)...
var cookies = new CookieContainer();
var response = await mock.PostAsync(url, content, cookies);
```

then, `cookies.Count` is always `0`.

So, I was wondering what is different than calling the actual server? Do I need to have additional headers? How can I set the cookies here?

Comment: This is not a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CookieContainer` passed to `PostAsync` method as a parameter. The fact that `PostAsync` adds cookies to `CookiesContainer` is a *side effect* of this method, a detail of **particular** `IHttpClientHelper` implementation. `new Mock<IHttpClientHelper>` creates **another** implementation which doesn't add cookies.

So, if you want mock to add cookies to a container it need an additional setup

```
mock.Setup(_ => _.PostAsync(It.IsAny<Uri>(), It.IsAny<HttpContent>(), It.IsAny<CookieContainer>()))
    .Callback<Uri, HttpContent, CookieContainer>((u, c, cookieContainer) => 
    {
        // Add required cookies here
        cookieContainer.Add(...);
    });
```

`Callback` is a method of `Mock` to setup side effects.

Comment: Just a question, can you please explain why the `Callback` here works? I'm new to `Moq`, but watching a few tutorials, I would think that `Callback` is called when there's a second call to the method. Is that right?